# Generic function wrapper for instrumenting function calls

Tags: dart

I am trying to build a generic function wrapper/decorator to instrument function calls. This is how far I got:

```
class _FunctionWrapper1<R, T1>  {
  _FunctionWrapper1(this._);
  final R Function(T1) _;
  R call(T1 a) {
    // here we can log or measure the call
    return _(a);
  }
}

class _GenericFunctionWrapper<F extends Function> {
  _GenericFunctionWrapper(this._);
  final F _;
  dynamic noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    // here we can log or measure the call
    return Function.apply(_, invocation.positionalArguments, invocation.namedArguments);
  }
}

void main() {
  final foo = (String s) => print(s);    
  final bar = _FunctionWrapper1(foo);
  bar("hello");
  final baz = _GenericFunctionWrapper(foo);
  baz("hello"); // does not compile
}
```

So, I can wrap a specific type, but I can't get a generic one to work.

I need something like:

`class _GenericFunctionWrapper<F extends Function> extends F`

Comment: Note that your generic version will throw away all type-safety.  If you don't care at all about type-safety, then you could do `dynamic baz = _GenericFunctionWrapper(foo);`, and then `baz("hello")` should work.  You could make a helper function or static method that constructs `_GenericFunctionWrapper` and returns it as `dynamic`.

Comment: Actually better it would be to present an F, but your proposal might work in my scenarios...